# Insert CheckBox value into SQLite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, checkbox

I have this database-query:

```
public void checkBox(String fasil1,String fasil2,String fasil3,String fasil4,String fasil5,String fasil6,String fasil7,
        String fasil8,String fasil9,String fasil10,String fasil11,String fasil12,String fasil13,String fasil14){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("fasil1", fasil1);
    cv.put("fasil2", fasil2);
    cv.put("fasil3", fasil3);
    cv.put("fasil4", fasil4);
    cv.put("fasil5", fasil5);
    cv.put("fasil6", fasil6);
    cv.put("fasil7", fasil7);
    cv.put("fasil8", fasil8);
    cv.put("fasil9", fasil9);
    cv.put("fasil10", fasil10);
    cv.put("fasil11", fasil11);
    cv.put("fasil12", fasil12);
    cv.put("fasil13", fasil13);
    cv.put("fasil14", fasil14);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("fasil", "name", cv);
}
```

and this is my CheckBox code:

```
fasil1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rs);
    fasil1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Rumah Sakit";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";

             }
        }
   });
    fasil2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.skul);
    fasil2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Sekolah";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";

             }
        }
   });
    fasil3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.kampus);
    fasil3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Kampus";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.officeBuild);
    fasil4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Office Building";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.apartemen);
    fasil5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Apartemen";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil6 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.hotel);
    fasil6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Hotel";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil7 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.bank);
    fasil7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Bank";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil8 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.spbu);
    fasil8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "SPBU";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil9 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.pasar);
    fasil9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Pasar";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil10 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.wisata);
    fasil10.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Jalur Wisata / Tempat Wisata";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil11 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.terminal);
    fasil11.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Stasiun / Terminal";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil12 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.bandara);
    fasil12.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Bandara / Airport";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil13 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.mol);
    fasil13.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Mal / Shoping Center";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
    fasil14 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.hiburan);
    fasil14.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                  checked = "Entertainment";
                  Toast.makeText(CobaCombo.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                  checked = "-";
             }
        }
   });
```

Then I have code to save values when button is clicked:

```
helper.checkBox(fasil1.getText().toString(), fasil2.getText().toString(), fasil3.getText().toString(), 
                    fasil4.getText().toString(), fasil5.getText().toString(), fasil6.getText().toString(), 
                    fasil7.getText().toString(), fasil8.getText().toString(), fasil9.getText().toString(),
                    fasil10.getText().toString(), fasil11.getText().toString(), fasil12.getText().toString(), 
                    fasil13.getText().toString(), fasil14.getText().toString());
```

But it's not work...
I want to store values ***checked*** into the database when checked or unchecked.
 How I can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: add name with checked or not using true or false...

Answer (score 1):

if a checkbox is checked you can get the bool value (true or false) with `value = checkbox.isChecked();`

if it is true, save as a 1 in your db, if not save as a 0

Answer (score 1):

**1st issue:**

You are assigning value to `checked` string variable on every checkbox checked, so at the end you will be having only 1 string value whether you have selected 2 checkbox or a single, Instead you should create String[] array for checked checkbox.

**2nd issue:**

On the button click, you are trying to call `checkBox` method of your database, here again you are just fetching a value of CheckBox caption, so it doesn't matter here whether checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: ehm,,you can make me e simple code to save value check box in database?reference from my code above??thank you for your feed back :)